# How to get rid of \n and \r in a string using python

Tags: python

I have written a python(2.7) program to retreive data from a table in a database and copy it into a csv file. There are various data in non-printable format(unicode) which contain \n, \r. Because of \n, \r I am not able to retreive the data as it is in the table.

I have tried the following

```
str.replace('\n','').replace('\r',' ')
str.replace('\n','\\n').replace('\r', '\\r')
```

but it did not work out

csv code

```
 cur.execute('select * from db.table_name)
with open('test.csv','w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in cur:
        print "row = ", count
        count = count + 1
        newrow=[];
        for index in range(0, len(row)):
            value= row[index]
            if(type(row[index])is str):
                 value=row[index].replace("\n"," ").replace("\r"," ")
            newrow.append(value)
       csv_writer.writerow(newrow)
```

Comment: I'm confused with that second replace line, what exactly do you want to happen there?

Comment: Why would you want to get rid of `\r\n` (they are linebreaks) and why wouldn't the replace work? please post some examples too

Comment: Show a small sample of code that generates your CSV incorrectly and we can likely show you how to fix it so these replacements are not needed.

Comment: this is the data '\r\xaeJ\x92>J\xe7\x1d\n\x89`\xc6\xf8\x9c<\x18' and I want to retreive it as it is i,e. without any line breaks

Comment: cur.execute('select * from db.table_name)
with open('test.csv','w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in cur:
        print "row = ", count
        count = count + 1
        newrow=[];
        for index in range(0, len(row)):
            value= row[index]
            if(type(row[index])is str):
                 value=row[index].replace("\n"," ").replace("\r"," ")
            newrow.append(value)
       csv_writer.writerow(newrow)

Comment: I have edited my code.

Comment: Add what the data looks like

Comment: Can you throw in the way the CSV looks? like I can't tell if you are got those actual '\r\n' characters showing or if it's just there but shown as a line break.

Comment: The data looks like this '\r\xaeJ\x92>J\xe7\x1d\n\x89`\xc6\xf8\x9c<\x18'

Comment: Add a `print(repr(value))` and add the output, does `.replace("\\r"," ")` have a different effect?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Thank you very much you saved my day.

Comment: No worries, seemed like the only logical possibility.

Answer (score 3):

`str.replace()` returns a new string, so you have to assign it to the original string to change it:

```
s = s.replace('\n','').replace('\r','')
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I have used the same as above

Comment: c'mon that was a simple thing that's why I didn't mention.

Comment: @kickbhatwoski: You'd be surprised how many times the problem is something simple like that.

Comment: @kickbhatwoski You won't be surprised that people post very incomplete questions with insufficient information.

Comment: Yes Sir my bad, but I corrected my question by editing it.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode has external serialized representations such as UTF-8 and UTF-16 and language-dependent internal implementations such as WCHAR. Your database read appears to have given you a UTF-16 serialized version of the string and all you have to do is decode it. You certainly don't want to remove the `\r` and `\n` because they are part of the multi-byte sequence and not really carriage return or newline at all.

As a simple example, I can remove all the the database and looping stuff and just work with the string you posted:

```
>>> value = '\r\xaeJ\x92>J\xe7\x1d\n\x89`\xc6\xf8\x9c<\x18'
>>> decoded = value.decode('UTF-16')
>>> print repr(decoded)
u'\uae0d\u924a\u4a3e\u1de7\u890a\uc660\u9cf8\u183c'
>>> print decoded
긍鉊䨾ᷧ褊왠鳸ᠼ
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, but @Padraic Cunningham gave the same answer few minutes ago.

Comment: Padraic asked you to post the result of `print(repr(value))` which is important to figure out how to interpret the back-slashes in the example string you gave us. You mentioned you are reading unicode data and I'm not convinced that you will solve the problem without decoding the unicode into a python `unicode` string.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you

Comment: That's a nonsense string.  Definitely not UTF-16.

Comment: It's a mix of Korean, Chinese, Mongolian and undefined codepoints...nothing coherent.

Comment: @MarkTolonen - It appears to be a mix of Hangul (Korean) and [CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs) which is an attempt to codify shared glyphs in Chinese Japanese and Korean. It seems reasonable that they would appear together in a string. As a person who only speaks English and Bad English, I really had no idea that the text itself was gibberish, so thanks for pointing that out! I will still stubbornly hold my position that OP should be decoding and encoding unicode strings to get the program to work.

Comment: @kickbhatwoski - are you saying that `.replace("\\r"," ")` worked? That's a very different solution than my suggestion. You said _There are various data in non-printable format(unicode) which contain \n, \r._ but unicode is printable so I looked to handling the Unicode instead of string replacements. Is the `repr` of that string really `'\\r\\xaeJ\\x92>J\\xe7\\x1d\\n\\x89`\\xc6\\xf8\\x9c<\\x18'` and removing `'\\r` really gives you the (still bizarre) data you want?!

Comment: It's not the .replace("\\r"," ") which worked, It's repr(str).

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to simplify your code:

For example:

```
import re
s = "Salut \n Comment ca va ?"
s = re.sub("\n|\r|\t", "",  s)

print(s)
```

Output will be as:

> Salut Comment ca va ?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do it by adding .strip() at the end of input
eg: n=input().strip()
it will remove all '/r' in strings